# Galerkin $L^2$ Projections

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, galerkin-methods

I'm struggling with a question:

Consider the domain $Ω = (0, 1)$, and the space $V ⊆ L^2(Ω)$ spanned by the basis functions
$v_1 (x) = 1$
$v_2 (x) = 1 + x$
Find the $Ψ^δ ∈ V$ which is the Galerkin $L^2$ projection of the function $Φ ∈ L^2(Ω)$ onto V , with $Φ (x) = x^2$

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

We know that $V=\langle\{v_1,v_2\}\rangle$, $\varphi=x^2$.

$\psi^\delta\in V$, so, there existe $\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\psi^\delta=\alpha_1 v_1+\alpha_2 v_2.$$

Since $\psi^\delta$ is the projection of $\varphi$ on $V$, it holds

$$(\varphi-\psi^\delta,v)=0\quad\textrm{ for all }v\in V,$$

or equivalently

$$(\varphi-(\alpha_1v_1+\alpha_2v_2),v_i)=0\quad\textrm{ for }v_i\in \{v_1,v_2\}$$

Now you have two equations with two unknowns. You can get $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$ and with that the projection asked.

Comment: Ok! That makes a lot of sense! Would you be able to expand on how I use these equations to get the unknowns?

Comment: Is only to write the information that you have. $(\cdot,\cdot)$ represents the inner product in $L^2(0,1)$, so you have $\displaystyle\int_0^1(x^2-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2(1+x))1)dx=0$  and $\displaystyle\int_0^1(x^2-(\alpha_1+\alpha_2(1+x))(1+x))dx=0$. Calculating those integrals you will obtain 2 equations with 2 unknowns.